# Is there a way to re arrange two data sets for one in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have data read as follows

**K**   *a  b   c*

p1   x  y  z

p2   e r  x

p3   v w q

...........
..............

p9  Y..........

**K**     *d  e  f*

p9  x  y  z

p8  o  p  q

p7  h  i  j

..............
............

**I like to re arrange data as follows**

**K** *a b c.......d  e  f*

p1 x y z ..............

p2  e r x ..............

p3 v w q.......

*
*
*

p7............h  i  j

p8........... o  p  q

p9  Y..........x  y  z

Index name is K, and one of index is 'k' too.
Can I turn my one of index into same index name and merge them into one?
Thank you in advance.

I divided them into 2 dfs, then

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Just `pandas.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But if it was one df, what would you do?

Comment: Maybe `pd.concat([df.loc[:'k'], df.loc['k':])`? (haven't tried, try to supply some "code format" sample data)